# found this error on migrating to viewpager2 androidx "Cannot resolve method 'super(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager)'"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

current code

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

        private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;
        private ArrayList<String> titles;

        ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = new ArrayList<>();
            this.titles = new ArrayList<>();
        }
```

Comment: That isn't one of the [constructors available](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter#public-constructors). Is there a reason you aren't using the constructor that takes a `Fragment` (if your ViewPager2 is within a Fragment) or `FragmentActivity` (if your ViewPager2 is directly in your activity's layout)?

Comment: also getting this error - 'ViewPagerAdapter(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity, androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle)' in 'com.example.uloimare.MainActivity.ViewPagerAdapter' cannot be applied to '(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager)'

Answer (score 0):

As of version androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-alpha03 FragmentStateAdapter now requires a Lifecycle object. Added two utility constructors to get it from the FragmentActivity host or the Fragment host.

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {    
    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager,Lifecycle lifecycle) {
       super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }
```

initialize FragmentStateAdapter

```
PageAdapter PageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());
```